# Integration of complex Excel data extraction/transformation and Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi

Looking for suggestions/recommendations

We currently have a report that has a large no. of metrics, across various areas of the business. The report is largely manually compiled. For many metrics, the data is sourced from some business system, then complex calcs/transformations are performed in Excel to get the metric, which is then manually 'plugged into' the report. The report is presented using Power BI

We want to automate the extraction/calculation process as much as we can. Both to reduce manual effort as well as to remove potential for errors/manipulation that can happen due to the Excel calcs.

Because the Excel transformations are so complex, we need to somehow keep the logic that's in the spreadsheets, but want to, as far as possible, secure the source data/calcs from human error/manipulation.

I think we need to somehow integrate the Excel data extraction/transformation logic into Power BI, and, as far as possible, remove any manual intervention required. And also remove any potential for unauthorised users to change source data or calculations. I'm not sure of the best way to go about this, so I'm looking for suggestions.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options.

1. Import the data into excel using macros, then export the completed data into a new sheet using macros.
2. Set up a powerquery which will do all the data manipulation for you given the raw data.

You'd probably need to post a specific example if you need more help.

Comment: thank you

please bear with me:

I'm not sure why 2 Worksheets are needed. Why import data into a Worksheet, then export it to another Worksheet?

What's the benefit in implementing the complex calculations in Power Query?